# Algorithm to check if any of a set of strings matches the input text?

Tags: algorithm

So, we have a set of multiple string and want the optimal algorithm to check if any of those strings can be found in the input text. The important thing is that we're not interested in finding all of the matching strings, it suffices to find one.

I've found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm It seems really good, but it finds all the matching patterns. Is there a way to get something even faster if we don't need that extra information?

Of course, we can just terminate the Aho Corasick algorithm when it finds the first matching pattern, but perhars there is another approach which will be faster for this type of problem?

Comment: The dictionary search operates at about O(N), saturating the memory-bus. Or, if the file is on disk: the I/O channel. So *effectively*, it can not be improved.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it *much* lower, because the complexity is

> The complexity of the algorithm is linear in the length of the patterns plus the length of the searched text plus the number of output matches.

and obviously, you must go over each of the patterns and the text.

The only thing to reduce is the number of output matches. But this is really simple. In the original algorithm, once an accepting state is met, it outputs all dictionary items matching it. For your variation, just mark an accepting state as accepting and output some "accept" symbol", or choose one dictionary item arbitrarily when constructing the FSM and output it.

Answer (score -2):

Just construct a Regex and let the libraries of your programming language do the hard work and optimization for you. I wrote that in C# recently: http://rextester.com/WFQNET2876